# Is (X,Y) bivariate normal in this case?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let (X, Y) be a bivariate random variable. It is known that $X|Y \sim N(\phi Y, \sigma^2)$ and $Y|X \sim N(\phi X, \sigma^2)$, for some known $\phi, \sigma^2, −1 < \phi < 1$.  Is (X,Y) bivariate normal? I want to say they are bivariate normal, but I don't know how to conclude.

I like this definition:  (X,Y)
being bivariate normal is "any linear combination of X
and Y
" is normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $|\phi|<1$.

Let $Z\sim N(0,1)$ be a normal rv, let $B$ be independent of $Z$, with $P[B=+1]=P[B=-1] = 1/2$.  Then the pair $(Z,BZ)$ is componentwise normally $N(0,1)$ distributed, but not jointly.  (For instance, $Z+BZ$ has a discrete component.)

Now let $X$ and $Y$ solve the equations
$$ \begin{pmatrix}1&-\phi\\-\phi&1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}Z\\BZ\end{pmatrix}.$$
(The condition on $\phi$ implies these equations can be solved.)
Then $$ X = \phi Y + Z \text{ and } Y = \phi X + BZ.$$
Since $(Z,BZ)$ are not jointly normal, neither are $(X,Y)$.
But conditional on $Y$ we have $X|Y\sim N(\phi Y, 1)$ since $Z\sim N(0,1)$, and so on.

Comment: This is the follow-up question, if you are interested in. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4708315/derive-the-marginal-and-joint-distribution-given-two-conditional-distributions