# Derive the marginal and joint distribution given two conditional distributions

Tags: probability, statistics

> Let $(X, Y)$ be a bivariate random variable. It is known that $X\mid Y \sim N(\phi Y, \sigma^2)$ and $Y\mid X \sim N(\phi X, \sigma^2)$, for some known $\phi$ and $\sigma^2$, with $−1 < \phi < 1$.
>
> i) Derive the marginal probability density functions of $X$ and $Y$.
>
> ii) Derive the joint distribution function of $X$ and $Y$.

My attempt is first I assume $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal. Then I know how to do the above. But I was told that $(X,Y)$ is *not* necessarily bivariate normal, which can be proved. Then I don't know how to this question.

But I guess my answer derived from the wrong assumption (just assume they are bivariate normal) may happen to be the correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

In the answer to this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4708249/is-x-y-bivariate-normal-in-this-case/4708281#4708281) of yours, it is proven by example, that the restrictions on the conditional distributions, does not necessarily imply that $(X,Y)$ is Gaussian. This is not the same as saying that $(X,Y)$ cannot possibly be Gaussian.

For instance if
$$\begin{pmatrix} X  \\  Y \end{pmatrix} \sim N_2 (0, \frac{\sigma^2}{1-\phi^2 }\begin{pmatrix}1 &  \phi \\  \phi & 1 \end{pmatrix}  ),$$
then it is also the case that $X|Y \sim N(\phi Y,\sigma^2)$ and $Y|X \sim N(\phi X,\sigma^2)$. The lesson to be learned is that generally the conditional distributions of $X|Y$ and $Y|X$ doesn't uniquely determine the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ nor the marginal distribtutions of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Thanks. I edit "not necessarily" in my question.  Yes, if I know it is bivariate normal, then I know how to solve the question.

Comment: @Jackie there are likely infinitely many different distributions satifying the given conditions. So the question is not specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

$$X=\phi Y+\sigma Z,\ Y=\phi X+\sigma Z_1\Rightarrow X=\frac{1}{1-\phi^2}(\phi Z_1+Z),\ Y=\frac{1}{1-\phi^2}(\phi Z+Z_1)$$ where $Z$ and $Z_1$ are $N(0,1)$ but $(Z_1,Z)$ is not necessarily Gaussian. I do not understand the claim that $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian. For instance if $\Pr(\epsilon=\pm 1)=1/2$ and is independent of $Z,$ taking $Z_1=\epsilon Z$ leads to $X=\frac{1}{1-\phi^2}(\phi \epsilon+1)Z$, whose law is only a mixing of two Gaussian densities.

Comment: Yes, X and Y are not Gaussian. Now the question is to derive the marginal density of X and Y, and joint density of X and Y.

Comment: You cannot derive the marginal density without further hypothesis: the possible laws of (X,Y ) are in a one to one correspondence with the possible laws of (Z,Z_1) when $Z$ and $Z_1$ are N(0,1)as explaind above.